# Airport booking system schema (ERD) guidance

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema

I have to make an ERD for an Airport. I have created and identified some entities but I am having some trouble connecting them among them. For the airport's booking system I have the following entities:

**Passenger**

**Ticket**

**Booking**

**Flight**

**Supplier**

I know that a passenger in order to board to the plane will have to have purchased a ticket, which he gets through the suppliers, in order to make a reservation/booking. Also all the tickets with the same flight code create the flight's manifest which I will have to save somewhere. A ticket, apart from other things, also keeps track of the passenger.

My try was: I personally would choose to have a ternary relationship between the supplier, the booking and the ticket. That way, these three are connected through a "buying" connection. However I don't know that to do with the passenger and manifest connections to the flight. E.g. I could abolish the "passenger" entity, and have it as a attribute inside the ticket. Then I would connect the ticket entity with the flight. But that seems kind of wrong, since  I flights board "passengers", not "tickets". I also thought of having a ternary connection between all 4 entities: passenger, ticket, supplier, and booking. But I don't know if that would be correct, and I also get lost as of what is considered best when there are many ways to accomplish this. Could anyone provide me with some guidance as of how to approach this? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Sketching out the `SELECTs` will provide you a lot more insight into the schema.  Also, think about 1:many versus many:many relationships between tables.

Comment: Don't forget a passenger can check zero to many bags!